# Caching dependencies, or copy them at injection?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, automapper, autofac

I have some configuration objects initialized by Autofac.
They are quite heavy to load (read the configuration file, deserialize it, verify some things, map the matching POCO object...).
But performances are fine because the registered object is declared as `.SingleInstance()`, so it's loaded only once, the first time it is injected somewhere, and after that the same instance is always used.

```
        builder.Register(c => _settingsReader.LoadSection(thing)) // Read and map object
            .OnActivated(t =>
            {
                // Do some checks on it to see if settings appear to be correct
            })
            .As(settingInterface)
            .SingleInstance();
```

But, these objects can be modified later (deliberately, or by accident), and as they are singletons the whole application will be affected if it happens.

The ability to be both able to update the initial singleton itself (to globally override defined settings) AND to update the local copy (to change the behavior of the object where the setting class have been injected, but not of the whole application) would also be interesting.

I thought about two possibilities :

- Ask Autofac to inject "copy" of objects, instead of the same instance, but I don't think there is a such "caching / copy" feature in it and I would lose the abilility to manipulate the singleton, or
- Use Automapper to deep-copy the object when it's injected, and store the copy in the dependant object instead of the original object. I'm fine with automapper (and the objects are very light so performance would not be an issue), but adding the copy for each injected property will burden either my Autofac configuration, or my objects themselves depending of where I place the "copy this object" code.

To use the Automapper idea, I'd have to do something like :

```
        builder.RegisterType<MyConsumingClass>()
            .WithParameter(
                new ResolvedParameter(
                    (pi, ctx) => pi.ParameterType == typeof(IMySettingClass),
                    (pi, ctx) =>
                    {
                        var mapper = ctx.Resolve<Mapper>();
                        return mapper.Map<ConcreteSettingClass>(ctx.Resolve<IMySettingClass>());
                    }))
            .As<IMyConsumingClass>();
```

Instead of just

```
        builder.RegisterType<MyConsumingClass>().As<IMyConsumingClass>();
```

(the previous code have not been tested, it's just here for example purpose)

I would really appreciate to have suggestions on best ways to handle this.

Comment: keep this class registered as singleton, register another one that would serve as scoped. inject singleton in the scoped service and use scoped one to clone configuration from its dependency and modify per scope without affecting singleton?

Comment: In my opinion, you can put constraints on the relevant classes to copy them to the singleton class when they changed.

Comment: Have you thought of [immutable classes](https://blog.ndepend.com/c9-records-immutable-classes/) and things like `init` properties so it _can't_ be changed later?

Comment: @YegorAndrosov interesting but it would force to have to separate classes, the initial singleton and the "holder" with a limited lifetime.

Comment: @isaeid of course, but it would still add some code to maintain for all of the classes applying the same logic.

Comment: @TravisIllig but I still need to change it sometimes ;)

Comment: So far I am gone for the "Automapper" solution, defined in Autofac Modules, as shown above (but with shorter code). It works well, it's almost centralized, and it's relatively short and efficient, and it also let met manipulate the singleton itself when required. I think I will keep it, unless I find something better.

Comment: Change a mutable copy, then create the immutable copy on change. Sort of how a lot of framework components return lists AsReadOnly enumerables.

Comment: make sure you post your own final answer and mark it as accepted

Comment: @YegorAndrosov I'm gonna do it soon, unless I find something better !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in comments, due to the lack of other proposals, I finally retained my own initial approach and used Automapper to clone my setting object when a new instance of the consuming class is created.
Here's an exemple for a Service and its setting object.
If your "setting" object have classes in its properties, remember to clone them also or you will only have a reference copy of the initial singleton ! To avoid this trap you could also use a true "clone library" more suited for this cases than Automapper.

```
public class ServiceFacadeModule
    : Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        // Modifying the settings on the service instance itself should NOT affect global setting object. To achieve this, settings classes are copied when initializing new service instances
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<ServiceSettings, ServiceSettings>();
        });

        var mapper = new Mapper(config);
        builder.RegisterType<ServiceDAO>()
            .WithParameter(
                new ResolvedParameter(
                    (pi, _) => pi.ParameterType == typeof(ISettings),
                    (_, ctx) => mapper.Map<ServiceSettings>(ctx.Resolve<ISettings>())))
            .As<IServiceDAO>()
            .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
    }
}
```